# how to get all number in javascript

Tags: javascript, function

I want to get all numbers in javascript and i write this.

**THIS**

```
<c:forEach items="${boardList}" var="board">
<tr>
<td><input type="hidden" class="boardNum" value="${board.num}">${board.num}
</td>  << here!!!!
<td><a class="boardTitle"
style="color: rgb(0, 100, 0);" >${board.title}</a></td>
<td>${board.writer}</td>
<td><f:formatDate value="${board.writeDate}" pattern="yy.MM.dd" /></td>
</tr>
</c:forEach>


<script>

var num = $(".boardNum").val();

var title= $(".boardTitle");

title.click(function(){
        alert(num);  >> only one number.
        </script>
```

i want all numbers.ex) board board.num(1~20)
but these codes in javascript is only one number (ex) num 20).

i think it will be using clouser but i dont know where to write clouser.

if what i think is not resolved, what do i do

ps) english is not good.

Comment: `num` doesn't change inside the for loop

Comment: sorry, i edit code

Comment: *ps) english is not good.* - struth mate

Comment: You will have multiple `.boardNum`. Using `.val` is kind of wrong. Try `$(this).closest('td').prev().find('.boardNum').val()` inside click handler. Also, if you are expecting dynamic elements, move to delegates. Try `$('parentContainerSelector').on('eventName', 'childSelector', handler)`

Comment: @LeeTaejun, do you mean that, on click of `title`, you need board numbers from all rows, irrespective of row title clicked?

Comment: @Arvind yes, i need all borrd Num

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var num = $(".boardNum").val();
```

Your current code fetches all elements having class as `boardNum`, however `.val()` will return value only for one element.

Assuming that you need all board numbers from hidden fields.

```
var boardNums = $(this).parents('table').find('input[type=hidden].boardNum').map(function(){return this.value;}).get();
console.log('all nums',boardNums);
```

OR

```
var boardNums = $('input[type=hidden].boardNum').map(function(){return this.value;}).get();
console.log('all nums',boardNums);
```

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over a jQuery object, executing a function for each matched element.
https://api.jquery.com/each/

```
var num = $(".boardNum");
num.each(function( index ) {
  console.log( index + ": " + $( this ).val() );
});
```